# How to generate a path by specifying controller and action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to generate a new link from my controller or helper. So I can't use the `link_to` method that is available in the view.

I want to generate the path by specifying the controller and action, not by using names paths. So e.g.:

```rb
{action: "index", controller: "accounts", id: "123"}
```

But what method do I put the above arguments into? I haven't seen a `Path.new()` method or anything like it.

Comment: You can use `link_to`, `*_path` or `url_for` in controller by including `url_helpers`:  `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url_for :controller => 'accounts', :action => 'index', :id => 123
```

**Note:**
In versions of Rails prior to `5.1`, url_helpers is not included in controllers by default. So you have to include it yourself:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to include any libraries in order to make it work? When I test it in my rails console it raises a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Got it, you need to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.